# select union count and group, multiple tables, postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi have 12 tables and I want to get unique values for some fields across all tables. 
by running the following query (I did a test between 2 tables) , I get an accetable result but the count is repeated if the unique value is stored in both table:

```
SELECT "mmsi", "type", "l", "w", "flag", COUNT (*) FROM test_1 GROUP BY "mmsi", "type", "l", "w", "flag"
UNION
SELECT "mmsi", "type", "l", "w", "flag", COUNT (*) FROM test_2 GROUP BY "mmsi", "type", "l", "w", "flag"
```

how can I solve it? thanks

Comment: Could your provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 5):

By aggregating each table, you get a result like this:

```
mmsi   type   l   w   flag   count(*)
123    456    A   B   C      12
123    456    A   B   C      25
234    567    X   Y   Z      17
234    567    X   Y   Z      11
```

because `UNION` doesn't detect any duplicates, because of the different count. And if there where two rows with the same count, one would be removed and the count accordingly too small by 50%.

You probably want this:

```
mmsi   type   l   w   flag   count(*)
123    456    A   B   C      37
234    567    X   Y   Z      28
```

instead with the total count, no matter in which tables. So get a set of all records first (with `UNION ALL`), then aggregate.

```
SELECT mmsi, type, l, w, flag, COUNT (*)
FROM
(
  SELECT mmsi, type, l, w, flag FROM test_1 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT mmsi, type, l, w, flag FROM test_2
) all_records
GROUP BY mmsi, type, l, w, flag
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try create an embedded query out of your original query and then to group by the original fields (excluding the count field) and sum the counts in the outer query.

This is some sample SQL demonstrating the idea:

```
select "mmsi", "type", "l", "w", "flag", SUM(c) from
(SELECT "mmsi", "type", "l", "w", "flag", COUNT (*) as c FROM test_1 GROUP BY "mmsi", "type", "l", "w", "flag"
UNION
SELECT "mmsi", "type", "l", "w", "flag", COUNT (*) as c FROM test_2 GROUP BY "mmsi", "type", "l", "w", "flag") q 
group by "mmsi", "type", "l", "w", "flag"
```

You will have to check, if the syntax is correct, but this should be enough to get an idea.

Answer (score 1):

maybe I have solved in this way:

```
SELECT "mmsi", "type", "l", "w", "flag" , COUNT (*)
FROM (SELECT "mmsi", "type", "l", "w", "flag" FROM test_1
UNION ALL
SELECT "mmsi", "type", "l", "w", "flag" FROM test_2) As test
GROUP BY "mmsi", "type", "l", "w", "flag"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  (select count(*) from table1 where ID = '123')
  + (select count(*) from table2 where ID = '456')
  + (select count(*) from table3 where ID = '789')
```

Comment: It's a good idea to add some explanation so users can make use of your answer more readily. code only answer sometimes wont serve the purpose for users and its difficult to understand -Review